# How to optimize this delete query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query:

```
delete FROM `customer` where customer_id 
not in (SELECT distinct customer_id FROM `order`);
```

But it's taking a long time, leading to timout and breaks in middle because `customer` table has more than a million records.

How can I make it fast? any alternative?

*edit*

Here is EXPLAIN of same with SELECT:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     customer    index   NULL    PRIMARY     4   NULL    127659  Using where; Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  order   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    25141   Using where
```

Comment: Is `customer.customer_id` and `order.customer_id` indexed?

Comment: Yeah some idea of the state of your indexes would help, but it may just be that your environment can't handle it. In SQL terms a million rows can be almost trivial or can be an impossibly big task, depending on your hardware and indexing strategy.

Comment: This question should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
DELETE customer FROM customer t1 LEFT JOIN `order` t2 on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id WHERE t2.customer_id is null;
```

Comment: I do prefer the JOIN but shouldn't that be `DELETE t1 FROM customer t1...` A note on foreign keys/indexes would be good too.

Comment: @Arth I think both is possible.

Comment: I'd be surprised, you can't do that in a `SELECT`.. even if possible I'd use the alias for consistency. I'd also use `c` and `o` for aliases, I prefer no alias at all to `t1` and `t2`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can remove DISTINCT from this DELETE command. It's not necessary here. So try this

```
delete FROM `customer` where customer_id 
not in (SELECT customer_id FROM `order`);
```

Second please check EXECUTION PLAN with this rebuild query

```
SELECT customer_id FROM `customer` where customer_id 
not in (SELECT customer_id FROM `order`);
```

This will show how MySQL executes this query and what's going on.